# How to solve suspected memory issue in custom WordPress loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, woocommerce-offtopic, memory

I have written a plugin that adds a "Where did you hear about us?" question to the WooCommerce checkout page and shows the results (as a simple horizontal bar chart) in a wp-admin page.

The plugin worked fine but has stopped working at some since I wrote it - seemingly, due to a memory issue.

In my wp-config.php file, I have...
`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');`
...and I have also tried `256MB`, `512MB` and `1G` - but not of these solve the problem.

`phpinfo()` reports a `memory_limit` of `1G` - so that seems fine.

So here is the function for my plugin which is where PHP appears to give up:

```
function get_customer_sources() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('processing', 'completed', 'cancelled', 'failed', 'refunded')
            )
        )
    );

    //$custom_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    global $post; // required
    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);

    $all_sources = array(); //The return array
    echo "<h1>START</h1>";

    //while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    //if ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);


        //echo "<h2>A</h2>";

        $order_id = $post->ID;

        //echo "<h3>Order ID: $order_id</h3>";

        if ( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Where did you hear about us', true) ) {

            $source = get_post_meta($order_id, 'Where did you hear about us', true);

            //echo '<h4>Order ID: ' . $order_id . ': ' . $source . '</h4>';

            // Fix the "Vegan event" vs "Vegan Event" problem
            $source = ucfirst(strtolower($source));

            // Add the source to the return array
            if (array_key_exists($source, $all_sources)) {
                // Increment existing value
                $num = $all_sources[$source];
                $all_sources[$source] = $num + 1;
            }
            else {
                // Add value
                $all_sources[$source] = 1;
            }

            //echo '<h4>Num sources: ' . count($all_sources) . '</h4>';

        }

        //echo "<h2>B</h2>";

    //endwhile;
    //endwhile; endif;
    endforeach;

    echo "<h1>END</h1>";

    return $all_sources;
}`
```

I thought maybe there was some bad data that was messing things up, so I changed the...

`if ( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Where did you hear about us', true) ) {`

...line to...

`if ( $order_id < 5000 && get_post_meta($order_id, 'Where did you hear about us', true) ) {`

...and it worked fine.

Next, I changed that line to...

`if ( $order_id >= 5000 && get_post_meta($order_id, 'Where did you hear about us', true) ) {`

...and it still worked.

But without the `5000` condition, the script just bombs out. (I know this because `<h1>END</h1>` is not outputted.)

So what is wrong with my code and/or how can I solve this problem of the method not completing? For example, could it be written more efficiently in terms of memory? Or is there a better approach? (You'll see from the commented-out that I have already tried using `WP_Query`, but I get the same results.)

NB - There are approx. 10,000 items returned by the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you ever need to visually dump 10.000 items to the user at once? Why not use paging? You might also have a PHP script timeout?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not visually dumping 10,000 items, but a single bar chart that is calculated from the 10,000 items. TheDeadMedic's answer has helped to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There are approx. 10,000 items returned by the query.

That's your problem right there. No matter what you do inside the loop, WordPress is still loading **10,000** post objects into memory.

Batch it up and sprinkle a little magic in your query arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'fields'         => 'ids', // MAGIC! Just get an array of id's, no objects committed to memory
    'posts_per_page' => 500,   // Batch size: big enough to reduce meta queries, small enough not to hammer memory
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'processing', 'completed', 'cancelled', 'failed', 'refunded' ),
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query;
$paged = 1;
$count = 0;
$total = null;

do {
    $args['no_found_rows'] = isset( $total ); // No need to SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS on subsequent iterations
    $args['paged'] = $paged++;

    $post_ids = $query->query( $args );
    update_postmeta_cache( $post_ids ); // Get all meta for this group of posts

    if ( ! isset( $total ) )
        $total = $query->found_posts;

    $count += $query->post_count;

    foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
        $source = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Where did you hear about us', true );

        // Do your stuff here



        // Wipe this post's meta from memory
        wp_cache_delete( $post_id, 'post_meta' );
    }

} while ( $count < $total );
```

Comment: Very nice approach! I assume you make a call to `update_postmeta_cache( $post_ids )` because we don't get it from `WP_Query` using `'cache_results'` as `true` or `'update_post_meta_cache'` as `true`, when we set  `'fields'` as `'ids'` (return too early for that)?

Comment: @birgire correct :)